# PSPAD setting up to open PHP files in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser

I have one simple question. How to setup a PSPAD editor to open/preview PHP files in Google chome, for example clicking on a shortcut key oopens from with a url: localhost/nameOfFile.php

I tried going into Settings -> Highlighter Settings -> php but dont know what to setup, into compiler,what parameters to enter,etc..

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I did find out, after hour of setting up.
All is needed to do was:

Go into Settings -> Highlighter Settings -> PHP -> External applications Tab -> In the field Application add the following: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %PHPFile%

The catch was in "%PHPFILE%" and I was using "%FILE%" flag.